# Windows Server 2003 as a PPTP Client

Tags: windows-server-2003

How do I setup Windows Server 2003 to connect to a MicroTik router PPTP VPN? Preferably without user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

This is [very well documented](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323441) by Microsoft.

> **To set up a client for virtual private network access, follow these steps on the
>   client workstation:**
>
> NOTE: You must be logged on as a member of the Administrators group to
>   follow these steps.
>
> NOTE: Because there are several versions of Microsoft Windows, the
>   following steps may be different on your computer. If they are, see
>   your product documentation to complete these steps.
>
> On the client computer, confirm that the connection to the Internet is
>   correctly configured.
>
> Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Network Connections.
>   Click Create a new connection under Network Tasks, and then click
>   Next.
>
> Click Connect to the network at my workplace to create the dial-up
>   connection. Click Next to continue.
>
> Click Virtual Private Network connection, and then click Next.
>
> Type a descriptive name for this connection in the Company name dialog
>   box, and then click Next.
>
> Click Do not dial the initial connection if the computer is
>   permanently connected to the Internet. If the computer connects to the
>   Internet through an Internet Service Provider (ISP), click
>   Automatically dial this initial connection, and then click the name of
>   the connection to the ISP. Click Next.
>
> Type the IP address or the host name of the VPN server computer (for
>   example, VPNServer.SampleDomain.com).
>
> Click Anyone's use if you want to permit any user who logs on to the
>   workstation to have access to this dial-up connection. Click My use
>   only if you want this connection to be available only to the currently
>   logged-on user. Click Next.
>
> Click Finish to save the connection.
>
> Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Network Connections.
>
> Double-click the new connection.
>
> Click Properties to continue to configure options for the connection.
>   To continue to configure options for the connection, follow these
>   steps:
>
> If you are connecting to a domain, click the Options tab, and then
>   click to select the Include Windows logon domain check box to specify
>   whether to request Windows Server 2003 logon domain information before
>   trying to connect.
>
> If you want the connection to be redialed if the line is dropped,
>   click the Options tab, and then click to select the Redial if line is
>   dropped check box.
>
> **To use the connection, follow these steps:**
>
> Click Start, point to Connect to, and then click the new connection.
>
> If you do not currently have a connection to the Internet, Windows
>   offers to connect to the Internet.
>
> When the connection to the Internet is made, the VPN server prompts
>   you for your user name and password. Type your user name and password,
>   and then click Connect.
>
> Your network resources must be available to you in the same way they
>   are when you connect directly to the network.NOTE: To disconnect from
>   the VPN, right-click the connection icon, and then click Disconnect.